# in browser JavaScript, I get error message when writing csv text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, navigator

In Browser JavaScript, I am trying to write some CSV data to the clipboard so that that user can paste to excel. Here is my code:

```
function onClick(){
      var txt=get_some_valid_csv_text()
      var items=[
          new ClipboardItem({
            'text/csv': new Blob([txt], { type: 'text/csv' })
          })
        ]
      navigator.clipboard.write(items)
}
```

The problem: It doesn't work, and I get this error message in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Sanitized MIME type text/csv not
>   supported on write.

Comment: CSV is text in essence, would using `text/plain` instead of `text/csv` work for you?

Comment: @FlorentRoques no, because it would paste like text in excel, so the user would need to further process it in excel. most likely though the text-to-data feature of excel.

Comment: Is this code on a secure (HTTPS) site or in a web extension?

Comment: @JaromandaX , its running on HTTPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer by trial an error. The secret, it seems, is to use text that is formatted as csv with **tabs** as separator rather than comma. No need for the ClipboardIteminterface, use can just use `navigator.clipboard.writeText`

This is the new code

```
function onClick(){
      var txt=get_some_valid_csv_text(sep='\t')
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt)
}
```

Comment: Which is then tsv and not csv. Besides that doesn't really answer the question even if it fixes your initial issue.

Comment: tsv yes, i never heard of that, but ii just looked it up and it does exists. Also, you can easily adjust the code to answer to the initial question by adding code to replace comma with tab `txt.replace(',','\t')`

Comment: No, the initial question is about the error thrown.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome is still [actively working on implementing this API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897289), and while [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#writing-to-clipboard) ask for UAs to support a bunch of MIME types, they currently only support `"text/plain"` and `"image/png"`.

So for the time being, we still have to rely on the ugly `execCommand('copy')` + wiring the copy event to set our own data...

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = (e) => {
  const data = `A1,B1
A2,B2
A3,B3`;
  document.oncopy = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // we handle it
    const dT = e.clipboardData;
    dT.setData( 'text/plain', 'this is plain text' ); // as plain text
    dT.setData( 'text/csv', data ); // as csv
  }
  document.execCommand( 'copy' );
  document.oncopy = null;
};

// to check what we have copied
document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]').onpaste = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const dT = e.clipboardData;
  console.log( 'retrieved "%s" as csv', dT.getData('text/csv') );
  console.log( 'retrieved "%s" as text', dT.getData('text/plain') );
};
```

```html
<button>copy to clipboard</button>

<div contenteditable>paste here</div>
```

Though I shall note I didn't try to paste this in MS Excel, so I don't know if that will fix your issue, but both Google Sheets and Apple's Numbers do only look at the *plain/text* value but are able to recognize CSV and TSV automatically.

Comment: @kaido, I just tried it, but it seems like it didnt have any effect. only the dT.setData( 'text/plain', 'this is plain text' ) worked. regardless i think i foudnd the solution iit is much simpler than i though. see my answer below

Comment: @yigal, yes I never said Excel was trying to read the text/csv part of the clipboard, I only said that to save with this MIME type, you still need the ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#writing-to-clipboard
this is all I could find,
"These data types must be placed on the clipboard with a corresponding native type description if added to a DataTransfer object during copy and cut events."
I really don't understand it :( but I hope it helps :)